# How to enter Unicode (or other) symbols in LaTeX within Apple Keynote (iWork)

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode, mac

In Keynote and other iWork apps, it is possible to enter formulas (and text) in LaTeX. This is an immensely valuable feature. But...

- How can I enter an astronomical (or other) symbol, via Unicode or by other means, *directly* in a LaTeX formula (ie. *without copying and pasting from the Character Viewer* — which doesn’t work anyway directly in the LaTeX formula editor within Keynote)?

  - For example, I wish to get the Mars symbol ♂ or the Venus symbol ♀ by entering `\mars` or `\venus`.

[This Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501) claims that one can also enter (ASCII) Unicode characters, but no indication is given there, in the blahtex documentation, or anywhere else about how to enter a Unicode character.

I’d also be happy with any non-Unicode route that allows me to enter such characters directly within the LaTeX coding within Keynote. Any approach by which I could use any of the astronomical symbols in the [LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) would be a dream.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about software that only shares syntax with (La)TeX, but cannot load packages

Comment: I assume then that all MathJax questions will be similarly closed?

Comment: I’m a bit surprised about the proposed question closure as well. The built-in LaTeX engine is `blahtex`, and the key to the solution, if there is one, will be a LaTeX trick, not an OS or application-based one. The current answer (and comment) are very close (and helpful!), I feel, but they propose workarounds which don’t precisely address the question.

Comment: There are indeed many questions here asking about editors that haven't been closed, while some have. I'm just looking for consistency as it factors into whether or not I take the time to answer. Reading the `blahtex` docs, I don't see a way to add new commands. We shall see what the management declares.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it using commands like `\mars` because those commands aren't in the subset of commands supported by `blahtex`. You can, however, enter the symbols using their unicode character codes.

Here's how I do it under macOS Catalina. Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard and select "Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar." Then select the Input Sources tab and make sure Unicode Hex Input is in the list of sources on the left. If it is not, click the + button to add it. Also make sure "Show Input menu in menu bar" is selected. Next, in your document click the flag-like icon in the menu bar and select Unicode Hex Input.

Now, to enter a unicode character, hold down shift-option (that's the shift and option keys simultaneously) and enter the character's code. The character should appear when you type the final digit of its code (e.g. 03B1 for a Greek `\alpha`). Of course you must know the code for the character you want. I don't know all the codes so I have to use the Character Viewer (remembering that the TeX font I want to use must contain the glyph or it won't show up in the final document). Unfortunately, not all of the astronomical symbols in the LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List are present. You may be able to find additional fonts that have them.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the tip from [latexerexetal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/218142/latexerexetal), I have a functioning *workaround*. It would be vastly preferable to enter normal LaTeX in a way that the `blahtex` engine could digest — after all, the `blahtex` documentation claims it supports Unicode character input.
For completeness, I repeat the process in full here.

- First, you have to enable the *Unicode Hex Input* keyboard in your *System Preferences* > *Keyboard* > *Input Sources*.
- Then, of course, you activate it, for example, by ticking *Show Input menu in menu bar*, then selecting *Unicode Hex Input* with your cursor in the menu bar.
- Once this keyboard is enabled, you can enter Unicode characters by holding down the Alt/Option key ⌥ on your keyboard and, while holding it down, typing the code for the Unicode character.
- You can find code for Unicode characters by, for example, from the same keyboard menu bar item, selecting *Show Emoji & Symbols*, which opens the *Character Viewer*.

That much was known. The workaround to get a Unicode character directly into a LaTeX formula with an iWork application (eg. Keynote, Pages) is:

- Once you open the editor for equations ( *Insert* > *Equation...* or ⌥⌘E ) to enter LaTeX code, you type `\text{ }`, and when your cursor is between those brackets in the text field, you type the code for the Unicode character as described above. (Just typing the Unicode code as text doesn’t get processed by `blahtex` for some reason, regardless of whether you use Unicode or UTF-8 codes.)
- Et voila, you have any Unicode character directly in your formula. For example:

  - `\text{⌥2642}` produces ♂
  - `\vec{R}_\text{⌥2642}` produces [image: vector R with subscript MarsSymbol]